# 42" Panasonic being recognized as a 65" with an ATI mobility HD 5400

Tags: 11.10

ati mobility hd 5400 card with dual monitors - laptop and panasonic 42" plasma.  Was working fine in 11.04 but after upgrading to 11.10 is recognising 2nd monitor as 65" and will only display as 720p.  Showing all resolution selections but says 1920x1080 cannot be displayed.

Is there an edit or command I can use to correct the problem?

Answer (score 1):

installed xubuntu and discovered more monitor selections.  Can now select higher hertz (60HZ) and 1080P selections but have to disable laptop monitor.  This was not possible with standard 11.10.